# Does OpenTSDB can perform 'clever' query?

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase, time-series, opentsdb

I really need to know if openTSDB database can perform some clever query. There are no lot of example shared.

For example, i need average for one dataset values, with zero values excluded.

Now i have something like this:

```
http://localhost:4242/api/query?start=1480892400&end=1483657140&m=sum:32d-avg:site.availability{siteId=73}&arrays=true&ms
```

This query takes start & end date timestamps, 32 days downsample parametar and 'avg' as average aggregate function, metrics name, tag and response format.

My time data series looks like:

```
[
  [1483142484722, 210],
  [1483142548883, 203],
  [1483142609002, 0]
]
```

Etc...

This query returns one single value as expected, that is average of all values in my dataset. I need query that returns average for all, except '0' values, i don't wont zero values affect my calculations.

Can we do something like that in openTSDB ?

Comment: Take a look at ATSD which runs on HBase and supports [SQL](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-docs/tree/master/api/sql#syntax) so you can filter values using the WHERE clause.

Comment: Can openTSDB calculate simple average for one metric ?